# Local action on node but path a child of node?

Tags: 7, navigation

I have created two local actions which I want to display on my nodes, General Configuration and Advanced Configuration.

General Configuration will show at node/%node, but Advanced Configuration is showing at node/%node/config. Is there anyway to keep the path as node/%node/config/advanced but have the local action display on node/%node?

```
  $items['node/%node/config'] = array(
    'title' => 'General Configuration',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
  );
  $items['node/%node/config/advanced'] = array(
    'title' => 'Advanced Configuation',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_ACTION,
    'weight' => 2,
  );
```

Thanks for any help